# Posting a JSON array to webservice in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json

I am having some problems with what should be a rather simple task. I simply need a JSON array with a single JSON object within it to be posted to my webservice. The entire URL request needs to be formatted like this:

`http://www.myserver.com/myservice.php?location_data=[{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"....}]`

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to append the 'location_data' bit using HttpPost. 
Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the HTTP connection method I am using:

```
    HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost hPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        hPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(string));
        hPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        hPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //execute request
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) hClient.execute(hPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I don't have any syntax errors, and my code is accessing the server fine, just not in the exact format the server needs. Any help on how to format my request to look like how I need it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Appending key/value data to URLs after a '?' is GET not POST.

This is how to POST data in Java:

```
String urlText = "http://www.myserver.com/myservice.php";
String postContent = "location_data=[{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}]";
try {
  HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlText).openConnection();
  c.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
  writer.write(postContent);
  writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Jim! Just to make it clear, if the code you wrote for me is POST, then will it still format it with the '?' like I need?

Also, how do i retrieve and store the server response using your method?

Thanks again

Comment: The '?' notation means GET, so you don't need this. I've never seen JSON sent to a server in this way, although it would be possible. The server response will come back on the connection as c.getInputStream()